# How to register collection of beans with application context and make eligible for autowiring?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, spring-boot, spring-ioc

I would like to create dynamic list of Spring managed beans in my @Configuration annotated AppConfig:

```
@Bean
List<SomeObject> createSomeObjects(@Value("${object.count}") final int objectCount) {

    List<Object> objects = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= objectCount; i++) {
        objects.add(new SomeObject())
    }
    return objects;
}
```

Then, I would like to inject this List of objects into another bean like this:

```
@Autowired
List<SomeObject> objects;
```

What I am getting is the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: java.util.List ..
```

I could create some sort of container for my object list, but am looking for a **more elegant** solution.

Comment: Simplest solution is to create a `SomeObjectList` bean that wraps your list. There is nothing inelegant about it, in fact injecting an unattributed list of objects is far less OOP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring handles collections specially, and this just doesn't work; the container always interprets a collection as the group of individually declared beans. [After some discussion and modifications it will work in 4.3](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-11269), but for now, the best solution is to use a holder class.

Answer (score 0):

[Since Spring 4, generics are fully supported during autowiring](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#_core_container_improvements). So just update your Spring version and it should work.

If you can't update, just autowire by bean name:

```
@Bean(name = "someObjectsList")
List<SomeObject> createSomeObjects(@Value("${object.count}") final int objectCount) {

    List<Object> objects = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= objectCount; i++) {
        objects.add(new SomeObject())
    }
    return objects;
}

@Autowired
@Qualifier("someObjectsList")
List<SomeObject> objects;
```

Comment: This does not work for me. Spring refuses to autowire successfully on startup.

Comment: What is your version of Spring? Can you paste full stacktrace? This may not be root cause of your problem.

Comment: I am using spring boot 1.3

Comment: OK, I think we are not seeing here root cause.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution should be no problem but your method,that creates the bean seems not to be public, so it may not be visible outside of the configuration class.
see [Chapter 3. Bean Visibility](http://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0-m2/reference/html/bean-visibility.html)